# Facebook not updating app name for app activity

Tags: android-activity, facebook-graph-api, feed

My app shows as php-sdk in the app activity feed

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=108252

Answer (score 1):

They are definitely my own. The app works fine, if you add it you can see for yourself.

http://apps.facebook.com/statusforsyria

And you'll probably notice that the activity feed still wants to call it php-sdk.

Comment: Also, if you check the link above that I posted in the body of the question, you'll see 2 others with the same problem. It is a Facebook updating bug. The app used to have php-sdk in the <title> of the iFrame page, and that would cause the canvas page to be called "php-sdk." However, now that is changed and it still shows by the wrong name in the app activity feed.

Comment: Does this persist after you run your page through the debug tool at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug ?  This should clear Facebook's cache of your URL and fix the title if it's incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the AppID and Secret are your own and not from another application named "php-sdk".